# Css and admin panel not working in Magento 2 Community Edition

Tags: magento2, php, magento-community

Hello I have installed Magento2 on my local Server in Ubuntu 14.

I downloaded it from official magento website without sample data.

I installed it and I am got this screen 
[image]

When I clicked on frontend url i got this screen
[image]

When I clicked on Admin Url I got this screen
[image]

I am not getting what went wrong from my side any help will be appreciable

Comment: run cli `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: it is not working similar problem i am facing

Comment: u can delete everything pub/static except .htaccess then run cli `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Comment: after running this command i got this error  --- The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
500

Comment: check Apache's mod rewrite... do you have an `.htaccess` file in your document root? is Apache's mod rewrite enabled? AllowOverride?

Comment: sir i resolved this issue i posted my answer please check if you find heplful please upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Database in "core_config_data" table there is "web/seo/use_rewrites" set it to 0.

after that clear cache:

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

reindex all:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Use url: http://localhost/MagentoCE/index.php/admin

Give permission to pub folder

```
chmod 777 -R pub
```

after that delete below folder

**var/view_preprocessed**

**var/cache**

**pub/static/frontend/Magento**

After deleting folder run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: it worked prashant but still my css is not loading please suggest something for that also

Comment: Check in console any 404 error for css?

Comment: didn't get please elaborate

Comment: view source (using cntrl + u) open css link. It is working or any error there

Comment: 404 error coming when I clicked on css link

Comment: Update answer check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37161/discussion-between-prashant-purohit-and-prashant-valanda).

Answer (score 1):

Try this **Before that take Backup**

1. Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static` folder
2. Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

**Note**: Remove entire files and folder under pub/static except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://www.dckap.com/blog/tag/magento-2-admin-links-not-working/ for the solution I think it will help you.

Comment: not relevant to my problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem i ran 2 commands after installing Magento 2

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

sudo find . -type d -exec chmod -R 777 {} \; 
&& sudo find . -type f -exec chmod -R 777  {} \; 
&& sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Now its working fine thank you all of you for answering

Answer (score 0):

Run this Query in database :

> INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign',
>   0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;

Then Run:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```