# Magento 2 problem with fresh install

Tags: magento2

The install seemed to finish without any issue at all however looking at the frontend and backend its not loading any css or js as seen in inspect tool in chrome developer tools.

Comment: Try My answer Here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96289/no-images-or-js-on-new-magento-2-installation/96291#96291

Comment: Refer it http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106838/css-and-admin-panel-not-working-in-magento-2-community-edition/106849#106849

Answer (score 1):

This One Worked for Me.
use this Command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Step 1 : In CMD Open your root directory using cd command

Step 2 : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` - run this Command

then,Check Your `pub/static` folder, CSS and Js files will be available there

Refer  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646623/i-have-installed-the-magento2-successfully-but-there-are-alot-of-js-error)