# Magento2 throws 500 internal server error

Tags: magento2.2, installation, permissions, apache2

I installed `Magento2.2`. After installing when I visit the site, it shows

> 500 Internal Server Error

The same for admin section as well.

I removed my .htaccess from root folder and tried. This time around front end loads without `css` and `js`, but admin section shows

> 404 Not Found

Can someone help?

I referred below but no luck.

[Css and admin panel not working in Magento 2 Community Edition](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106838/css-and-admin-panel-not-working-in-magento-2-community-edition)

My Apache error log says

> [Sun Jan 21 16:40:19.568718 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12172:tid 1100] [client ::1:56158] D:/wamp/www/anto/certification/magento2/.htaccess: Invalid command IfVersion, perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration,

Comment: Please check server log. where you can get cause of it

Comment: @PramodKharade I updated my log

Comment: run this command  and update composer once :  php bin/magento setup:upgrade,php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy , give permission check.

Comment: @PramodKharade your hint helps. I need to enable `mod_version` in httpd.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 500 error, you need to enable mod_version in apache.

You can check all the enabled apache modules with the command `apache2ctl -M`. If you don't see it in the list, then it's not installed.

To do this run the command `a2enmod version` as the root user, or `sudo a2enmod version` as a non-root user and then reload apache with `apache2ctl reload`.

For 404 error regarding css and js, you can try changing:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

to

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

in the `.htaccess` file located in the following locations:

- your Magento root install directoy (this is usually the `/www/` or `/public_html/` folder)
- `/pub/`
- `/pub/static/`
- `/pub/media/`

Comment: Thanks for your time. Enabling `mod_version.so` fixed the issue. +1 for your support.

Answer (score 4):

As per the suggestion given by  @Pramodkharade on comments, I need to enable mod_version module from my `httpd.conf`

Change below

`# LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so`

To

`LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so`

And the restart apache this will fix the issue.

Comment: If @Lez answer helped you then you must mark that answer as supported rather posting as a answer.

Comment: Indeed, what @Lez posted should be marked as answer, not your own post, lol.

Comment: @talonkingvskg Done.

Answer (score 0):

magento2 .htaccess problem after server migration from siteground to godaddy. internal server error on image,css,js
and my website is http://mastee.in/

i have migrated from siteground hosting to godaddy. and i dont have access to any image, links, css, js files . i am guessing the problem is with .htaccess file

can anyone address what went wrong?

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bot|crawl|robot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(bing|Google) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?.*$ "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1" [R,L]
# BLOCK BLANK USER AGENTS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

error with all css,images,js files

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 webmaster@mastee.boilerinstallers.london to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: the problem was fixed by the mod_version source -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206042/35757