# Question about static URLS

Tags: magento2

I'm very new to magento and was tasked to migrate this magento site (https://swadeshiherbal.com) but I'm getting this 500 errors from non existing urls.

```
e:g https://swadeshiherbal.com/static/version1653542305/frontend/Alothemes/geckoOrganic/en_US/mage/calendar.css
```

Don't know how there are generated or where actually these resources located. Please help me to debug this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You had "500 internal server error" on static files.

Looks like your Apache didn't enable `mod_version` yet, you need to enable it from the `httpd.conf` configuration file.

1. If you don't know where that file is located, you can run `httpd -V` in the terminal (command name depends on your system/apache version, it can be also `apache -V`).
   Then look for the result like this:

```
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"
```

Open the `httpd.conf` file and change below

```
# LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
```

To

```
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
```

Finally restart apache.

2. In case your server does not allow enable `mod_version.so` module, you can take a look at this topic [Magento 2: Apache mod version not enabled/installed/allowed by host, causes 500 error on all pages due to failing .htaccess files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206039/magento-2-apache-mod-version-not-enabled-installed-allowed-by-host-causes-500/206042#206042)

Reference: [Magento2 throws 500 internal server error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210326/magento2-throws-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: If this answer helps you resolve your issue, please mark it as **accepted**. That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for your reply. but upon checking on easyapache4 configurations on whm it seems mod_version is already installed https://www.screencast.com/t/FDPOzqgqv

Comment: Let's try to run the following commands from your Magento root folder: `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/ && rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` and then check the result.

Comment: I'm getting another error now mate. "Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled"

Comment: You are not getting "500 internal server error" anymore, the error "Refused to apply style from '...en_US/css/local-l.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') " indicates the file local-l.css does not exist. You should find where are calling that file then fix the issue.